# Insert Data into MySQL using php

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO photo '.
   '(id,cid, path,date) '.
   'VALUES (,`$cid`, `$new`,)';
```

There are four columns in the table, "photo".

```
1) id - auto increment 
2) cid - $cid
3) path - $new
4) time - timestamp
```

Now I want to insert new data only to the cid and path fields. How can I do it with the above mentioned code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//$con = you connection
$sql = "INSERT INTO photo (cid, path) VALUES ('$cid', '$new')";
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your query

1. You have used tick mark around the variables which is invalid
2. Unwanted `,` at starting while entering values
3. This is not an error, but an advice:There is no need for breaking a query into several parts until it is large.

For inserting only `cid` and `path` Do like this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO photo (cid, path) VALUES ('".$cid."', '".$new."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

this is as simple try this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO photo (`cid`, `path`) VALUES ('$cid', '$new')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you know the value of `id` and `date` column value then pass it, other wise you just skip it or atlast pass the default value.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO photo (cid, path,`date`) VALUES ('$cid', '$new',now())";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO photo (cid, path,`date`) VALUES ('$cid', '$new',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
```

Answer (score 0):

1st of all... this is how you do debugging:

Run the query in phpmyadmin (echo query from php then run in phpmyadmin to see exactly what error you are getting, then adjust and test until it works properly

2nd: The ID. Either you lose it, like other people suggested above or you set it NULL and it gets auto incremented if it's set right in the schema.

I'm not trying to just give you a solution, i'm trying to get you some information, so you don't have to ask the next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO photo (id,cid, path,date) VALUES (NULL,'".$cid."', '".$new."',now())";
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```